# i want to post text to chatter by clicking a button

Tags: apex, visualforce

i dont know how to start to achieve my task,guys please suggest me ,how to start,i want to create a vf page having a inputtext field and button ,,after giving text ,if i click button,then my text will be shown in chatter,thanks in advance.

```
<apex:page controller="chatterclass">
  <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock >
  <apex:pageBlockSection >
  <apex:inputText value="{!entertext}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>
  <apex:pageBlock >

  <apex:pageBlockButtons >
  <apex:commandButton value="post to chatter" action="{!sendtoChatter}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockButtons>
  </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class chatterclass {
public string entertext{get;set;}
public chatterclass (){
}
public void sendtoChatter(){
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these sample codes

```
//Adding a Text post
FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
post.ParentId = oId; //eg. Opportunity id, custom object id..
post.Body = 'Enter post text here';
insert post;

//Adding a Link post
FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
post.ParentId = oId; // Record Id eg. Opportunity id, custom object id..
post.Body = 'Enter post text here';
post.LinkUrl = 'http://www.google.com';
insert post;

//Adding a Content post
FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
post.ParentId = oId; // Record Id eg. Opportunity id, custom object id..
post.Body = 'Enter post text here';
post.ContentData = base64EncodedFileData;
post.ContentFileName = 'infallible.pdf';
insert post;
```

You can post any type of chatter post. In the body part give your custom message which will be `entertext` and give the record Id on which you want to make this post.

Comment: i want to post it on chatter,,i dnt know,how to get the id of chatter.

Comment: @sahisfdc you don't need chatter Id. For testing use first post and add your message and for testing hardcode some record. then check.

Comment: can u please guide me to post text for all users in my org

Comment: @sahisfdc You can post them in group.